# Cannot reach exposed external ip on google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I followed the kubernetes-engine tutorial, used local gloud in terminal. Looks everything is working, but I can't reach exposed external-ip http://104.197.4.162/ in my browser, as the tutorial said. Thank you!

$ kubectl get service

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
hello-web    LoadBalancer   10.11.245.151   104.197.4.162   80:30135/TCP   1m
```

$ kubectl get pods

```
NAME                         READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-web-7d4f9779bf-lw9st   1/1       Running   0          1m
```

$ kubectl describe svc hello-web

```
Name:                     hello-web
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=hello-web
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=hello-web
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.11.245.151
LoadBalancer Ingress:     104.197.4.162
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30135/TCP
Endpoints:                10.8.0.6:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

$ curl 104.197.4.162:80

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 104.197.4.162 port 80: Connection refused
```

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app

Comment: please provide output of `kubectl describe svc hello-web`

Comment: Updated! I attached the output details! Thank you!@Radek'Goblin'Pieczonka

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Denly Did you manage to get this working ? I am able to run through the tutorial and get that to work externally but I would like to use the Nginx docker application instead of the hello-app but when I do that I cannot get the external site to load ?

Comment: @Denly have you resolved the problem you mentioned above? I have also faced with the same one & I need help at that point

Answer (score 2):

I think you need opening firewall and access your deployments in compute engine instance by instance external ip address and port. You can use `curl ip:port` in for check it.

Comment: It tried. It failed quickly and shows this. "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 104.197.4.162 port 80: Connection refused". I'm going to check firewall.

Comment: @Denly If you want just expore, you can use instruction how to deplout and access to my aplication: https://gist.github.com/trigun117/0a0e88749582132244d6e036780207aa

Answer (score -3):

As per the tutorial says, and I quote it:

> Note: Kubernetes Engine assigns the external IP address to the Service
>   resource—not the Deployment. If you want to find out the external IP
>   that Kubernetes Engine provisioned for your application, you can
>   inspect the Service with the kubectl get service command
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get service
> NAME         CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
> hello-web    10.3.251.122    203.0.113.0     80:30877/TCP     3d
> ```
>
> Once you've determined the external IP address for your application,
>   copy the IP address. Point your browser to this URL (such as
>   http://203.0.113.0) to check if your application is accessible.

So, you'll need to run `$ kubectl get service hello-web` to know the IP address.

Comment: Hi I did use the external IP address